# What does the end of this sentence mean?

Tags: grammar

http://www.berfrois.com/2013/11/ron-rosenbaum-on-auden-larkin-and-love/
I don't understand the structure of the second half of this.

The stanza in which the line occurs is admittedly not his best, **concerning itself as it does with the poet speaking truth to power in a self-congratulatory way**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing that is probably giving you trouble is the construction *concerning itself as it does*. This is an instance of the general construction *VERBing as SUBJECT DO*<sup>tense,person</sup>, which is a way of saying *since SUBJECT VERB*<sup>tense,person</sup> *(so much*). Thus:

> Disliking Bob as I do I will not vote on his promotion. =  Since I dislike Bob so much I will not vote on his promotion.
>
> Concerning itself as it does with ... = Since it concerns itself with ...

The other piece that may confuse you is *speaking truth to power*. Rosenbaum here uses the word *power* [metonymically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) to represent the ironically capitalized entities ‘Authority’ and ‘the State’ in Auden's poem.

The sentence may be paraphrased, then:

The stanza in which the line occurs is admittedly not his best, **since it shows Auden congratulating himself on bravely telling the powers-that-be a truth they do not want to hear.**

Comment: It’s a book that recognizes the banal struggle of our daily lives and yet considers it nothing less than a tragedy that these lives, filled as they are not only with boredom but with fjords and cigarettes and works by Dürer, must all end in total annihilation.

Comment: I found this here.(http://www.nybooks.com/articles/archives/2013/dec/05/zadie-smith-man-vs-corpse/?pagination=false&printpage=true) this has the same structure but it is not "because" but "although", I thought. Does this "ing as S does" also have the function of "although"?

Comment: @kih1930 Yes, that's a nice paraphrase.